# Ubuntu mail PHP port error

Tags: php, email, ubuntu, port

I was able to send mail up until last week when godaddy changed there mail server name. Im not sure what file to update with the new server name.

Im getting this error message when trying to send mail:

```
Failed to connect to smtpout.secureserver.net:25 [SMTP: Invalid response code received from server (code: -1, response: )]
```

Where/what do config file do i edit on my Ubuntu server?

Thanks

Comment: i think the problem is with the remote server

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed a mail server like Postfix on your server? Normally once it's done you don't have a lot of things to change. The last configuration you have to do is in your php.ini file (probably in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini) there are SMTP settings to set.

Comment: it was working but godaddy changed the server and port. Just not sure where to update that. PEAR is installed on this server as well.